# Can't find the .exe file to install gitpad

Tags: git, github

This might be a total newbie question, as I am very new to Git and Github.
I want to install Gitpad from Github ( https://github.com/github/GitPad ), but I can't find the .exe file mentioned in the "How to install" part.
Clicking on the link "Click this link" doesn't work either (gives me an error) and when I download the Zip, there is no .exe file in the folder.

Comment: There is an issue filed regarding the download link beeing broken (https://github.com/github/GitPad/issues/22)

Comment: @joran Thanks for the explanation !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GitPad.exe from the Download page](https://github.com/downloads/github/GitPad/Gitpad.zip)

by [github blog](https://github.com/blog/975-gitpad-write-your-commits-in-notepad)

Comment: Thanks a lot. How did you get to the download page from the github page?